# Show that the component function v(x, y) has maximum and minimum values in R which are reached on the boundary of R and never in the interior

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the function f (z) = u(x, y) + iv(x, y) be continuous on a closed bounded
region R, and suppose that it is analytic and not constant in the interior of R.
Show that the component function v(x, y) has maximum and minimum values in
R which are reached on the boundary of R and never in the interior, where it is
harmonic.

I have a general guess that we would approach this using the maximum modulus principle, but what would the formal proof look like?

Comment: Harmonic functions have a certain mean value formula. which can be proved rigorously. Using this formula, the principle comes out directly.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I am not sure what you mean. Would you be able to clarify this?

Comment: The mean value formula for harmonic functions, says that suppose $a$ is an interior point of your domain, and $B(a ,\epsilon)$ is a ball of radius $\epsilon$ around $a$ contained inside the domain of the function $v(x,y)$, which is harmonic. Then, the integral of $v(x,y)$ in the ball, is actually just the value of $v$ at $a$, times the volume of the ball. That is, the value of $v$ at $a$, is like the average value of $v$ in any ball around $a$. With this in mind, can you say why maybe any maximum or minimum must be attained in the boundary?